# Pandas: Column' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to strip all the values after 'H' and store it to a column.

`df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('H').str[0]`

But pyspark gives me error : Column' object is not callable

Comment: `df['col1'].str.split('H',expand=True)`

Comment: @Wen but still the same error

Comment: Is this pandas or pyspark? It can't be both.

Comment: pandas on spark

Comment: Really... restart your kernel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is add `expand=True` for `DataFrame` and then select second column:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('H', expand=True).iloc[:, 1]
```

Or:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('H', expand=True)[1]
```

Comment: In pyspark are implemented `.str` functions? How working e.g. `df['col1'].str.lower()`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - In pandas need replace `NaN`s to `int` by `fillna`, then is possible replace to int like `df['col'].fillna(0).astype(int)`